# How to store and retrieve an array to and from SQL database table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have to insert a string into a column of a table. But due to presence of characters like ''(inverted commas) Sql server is not accepting the string as whole. So i wanted to store the character's unicode(integer) values instead of storing the characters of the string into that column. For this i am using array. I want to know how to insert the arrays(elements of array) into the table column and plus how to retreive them one by one so that i can convert them back to a string. Please Help.. Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

You're down the wrong track. What you are experiencing is a SQL Injection problem which means that you are building your SQL statements as strings. That is always a bad option. In this case you've created a bug, but in many contexts it creates a severe security risk.

If you convert the SQL statement to be a [parameterized query](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06) you won't have the issue any more and won't have to deal with arrays or other quirky workarounds.